# Dropdown menu closes when I hover the options in Firefox

Tags: css, pug, dropdown

Im using Jade and CSS for a dropdown menu

here is the jade:

```
    .dropdown
        button.dropbtn(type="button") Me
          .dropdown-content
            a(href="/favorites") 
              | Favorites
            a(href="/update") 
              | Edit
            a(href="/logout")
              | Logout
```

and here is the css:

```
.dropdown{
  position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content a{
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropbtn {
    background: none;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    background: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-content{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content{
  display: block;
}
```

This basically makes it so that when you hover over the "me" button
the dropdown buttons appear, but when I move down the cursor to select one
they (edit: they meaning the dropdown menu options that appear on hover) immediately disappear.

Seems like this doesn't work in Firefox but does in Chrome.

edit:
turns out I needed to change the jade to the following (thanks to  Kai Hao for the help):

```
      .dropdown
        .dropbtn
          | Me
          .dropdown-content
            a(href='/favorites')
              | Favorites
            a(href='/update')
              | Edit
            a(href='/logout') 
              | Logout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by **they**? In my computer it actually works.

Try changing `position: absolute` to `relative` for the dropdown menu. Maybe it won't work because the `.dropbtn` height only stretch for itself, so when you hover down the cursor, you are not pointing at it anymore. `position: absolute` in your `.dropdown-content` won't make it stretch the parent content. There is going to need some additional css adjustment though.

```
.dropdown-content{
    display: none;
    position: relative; /* here */
}
```

---

```css
.dropdown{
  position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content a{
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropbtn {
    background: none;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    background: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-content{
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropbtn">Me
    <div class="dropdown-content"><a href="/favorites">
         
        Favorites</a><a href="/update">
         
        Edit</a><a href="/logout">Logout</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this allows me to hover over the dropdown options however, besides the alignment being off, I actually cant click anything, it just selects the whole .dropbtn div (even after changing z-indexes)

Comment: what browser/OS are you using?

Comment: firefox on ubuntu

Just tested chrome and it works but I guess this just makes it a new issue. Ill update that in the main post

Comment: try change your `button` to `a`

Comment: still has the same issue

Comment: changing to `div` works for my firefox/Windows. I've added the code snippet above. please try that.

Comment: thank youu so much! this worked! I will update my answer with the jade format of your html snippet